# max magnitude: finding max magnitude among integers

Tags: python

```
import math
def max_magnitude(val1, val2, val3):
   
    
    if abs(val1) > abs(val2) and abs(val3):
        return(val1)
    elif abs(val2) > abs(val3) and abs(val1):
        return(val2)
    elif abs(val3) > abs(val2) and abs(val1):
        return(val3)
def main():
    val1 = int(input())
    val2 = int(input())
    val3 = int(input())
    
    print(max_magnitude(val1, val2, val3))
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

input:
25 0 -50
expected test: return correctly -50
but
my output test : return incorrectly 25

someone help me to fix that error while texting

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you have written a lot of unnecessary code. Let's simplify that by using `map()`.

```
def max_magnitude(val1, val2, val3):
    return max([val1,val2,val3],key=abs) # Return the max value of abs
```

`max()` basically returns the maximum value present in an iterable. The `key` arg of `max()` helps us pass `abs` as an argument.

The whole code looks like this:

```
def max_magnitude(val1, val2, val3):
    return max([val1,val2,val3],key=abs) # Return the max value of abs
def main():
    val1 = int(input())
    val2 = int(input())
    val3 = int(input())
    print(max_magnitude(val1, val2, val3))
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks to @j1-lee → `map() not needed`

Docs:

[max()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Comment: Yes, I updated it and also added support for returning exact value rather than abs().

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one line with `sorted()`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    val1, val2, val3 = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
    print(sorted([val1, val2, val3], key=lambda x: abs(x))[-1])
```

```
25
0
-50
-50
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you meant to do

import math

```
def max_magnitude(val1, val2, val3): 
    
    if abs(val1) > abs(val2) and abs(val1) > abs(val3):
        return(val1)
    elif abs(val2) > abs(val3) and abs(val2) > abs(val1):
        return(val2)
    elif abs(val3) > abs(val2) and abs(val3) > abs(val1):
        return(val3)
def main():
    val1 = int(input())
    val2 = int(input())
    val3 = int(input())
    
    print(max_magnitude(val1, val2, val3))
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The code  can be simplified by a lot.

Comment: Yes, definetely. But this was not the case here.

Comment: Well why not if you could simply it and help them.

Comment: "someone help me to fix that error while texting" -> nothing about optimizing. You asked where you made mistake and I pointed it out.

Comment: [Write to the best of your ability](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Where do I force anything to anyone?